# is posible call public view return deployed, from anther contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Reading about the documentation.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types

I have seen that one contract can call another, but they use gas.
It is possible to call a function like **public view return**
From another **contract public view return**?

The example would be something like that I have:

PointA

```
contract PointA {
    uint256 number = 10;
    
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

PointB

```
contract PointB {
    address PointA = 0x9a6120275387Dc5Aa5dab0D87aeeee5894A3411B;

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 PointA = PointA.call(bytes4(sha3("retrieve()")));
        return PointA;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the full chain of calls is (read-only) [calls](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call), not  [transactions](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#parameters-23).

PointA.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract PointA {
    uint256 number = 10;
    
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

PointB.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface PointA {
    function retrieve() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract PointB {
    PointA pointA = PointA(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138);

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 retrieved = pointA.retrieve();
        return retrieved;
    }
}
```

When you **call** (not transact to) `PointB` function `retrieve()`, it makes an EVM **call** to `PointA` function `retrieve()`.

---

The naming of the `call()` function from your question is a bit unfortunate. It executes an EVM call (or sometimes called "message call", [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters)), but it's not related to the `eth_call` (read-only, gas-free) RPC method.

Comment: What reason are you, I had not fallen into that possibility, an example method should be included in the documentation, so that everyone could feed. Thanks you

Comment: One question, why PointA pointA = PointA (, does it receive the address if it is not an address type?

Comment: It's not calling the `PointA` constructor... It's creating a pointer to the address of the already deployed contract (that's why you're passing the address), assuming it implements the `PointA` interface.