# How can I find out the token balance of an address?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am using the contract from: https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c#readContract

I have seen that it has a public variable which is:

```
mapping (address => uint) public balanceOf;
```

I am trying to call in my contract, but it is not very clear to me how to use it, if via interface or in what way

```
contract checkBalanceOf {
    mapping (address => uint) public  balanceOf;
    function balanceOf() public returns (uint256) {
        address  ERC20Address = targetInterface(0x18895B2a605CdAb301482d8F96E59FaDc17964C3);
        return ERC20Address.balanceOf(bankAddress);
    }
```

I was trying to apply the logic of this answer, but unlike, that this one does not have a public function

[is posible call public view return deployed, from anther contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015820/is-posible-call-public-view-return-deployed-from-anther-contract)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check how many [WBNB](https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c#readContract) the `bankAddress` owns, and to perform the check from your own contract, your contract needs to:

1. Define the `balanceOf()` function in an interface
2. Instantiate the interface pointing to the `WBNB` contract address
3. Call the `WBNB` function `balanceOf()` passing it the `bankAddress`
4. *Recommended:* Wrap the call in a `view` function so that by default it uses a call, not a transaction, in some client apps.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IBEP20 {
    // mind the `view` modifier
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256);
}

contract checkBalanceOf {
    address bankAddress = address(0x123);

    // mind the `view` modifier
    function balanceOf() external view returns (uint256) {
        // creating a pointer to the WBNB contract
        IBEP20 WBNBContract = IBEP20(0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c);

        // getting balance of `bankAddress` on the WBNB contract
        return WBNBContract.balanceOf(bankAddress);
    }
}
```